# Laravel 5.1 array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.1 
And I need to convert array to diffrent array
So I am having

```
$wells = Well::get(array('well_id' => 'url','well' => 'name','iso3'))->toArray();

$users= User::get(array('id' => 'url', 'name' => 'name'))->toArray();
```

So from bouth of the arrays the output should be converted from well_id to url from wells and id to url from users. So even if they are different from the database the output will have the same 'name' because after I am having a function for both but it uses this 'name'.
So the examle I have given is not working but it should be something like this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select function of Laravel

```
$wells = Well::select('well_id as url','well as name','iso3')->get()->toArray();
```

and

```
$users= User::select(array('id' => 'url', 'name' => 'name'))->get()->toArray();
```

i haven't try it but it should work.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thanks mate.